# Extract data from url (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, json

http://accounts.fstatic.org/json/results/?callback=google

I need extract all results from here.

Edit: Extract results by id: example

$result1 = result['1'];
$result2 = result['2'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curl to fetch data and decode the json to array in php.

```
<?php

$json=fetchPageFromURL('http://accounts.fstatic.org/json/results/?callback=google');
$obj=json_decode($json,true);
print_r($obj);

echo "<hr>";

foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    foreach (array('result','url','v-url','title','content') as $nnn => $keyname) {
        if(0===strpos($key, $keyname)){
            $id=substr($key, strlen($keyname), strlen($key)-strlen($keyname));
            $fin[$id][$keyname]=$value;
        }
    }

}

print_r($fin);

function fetchPageFromURL($url){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Updated to fetch details and put them away.

Comment: I need return data by ID: Ex: $result1 = $result1->result1;

Comment: You mean such as ['1'=>{'result'=>XX,'url'=>YY,...},...]?

Comment: Yes, i need get the data like your example

Comment: Updated for that sample's format.

Answer (score 1):

```
$results = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://accounts.fstatic.org/json/results/?callback=google'));
```